# Python Pandas: I'm unable to set second row as column headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have an .xlsx file whose format is similar to... (Note that the first row is descriptive and not meant to be the column headers. Headers are on row 2)

```
SHEET SUBJECT, Listings for 2010,,,,
Date, Name, Name_2, Abr, Number,         <--- I want this as column headers
12/01/2010, Company Name, Somecity, Chi, 36,
12/02/2010, Company Name, Someothercity, Nyc, 156,
```

So when I do `this_df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')` I get `SHEET SUBJECT` and `Listings for 2010` followed by a series of unnamed column headers. Expected, not what I want.

And when I do `this_df.columns = this_df.iloc[1]`, assuming I'll get the column headers set from the row at index 1, it instead gives me the data values from the row at index 2.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: `pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', header = 1)`

Comment: Your solution was the first I tried and it worked, thanks. If you wanna move it to an answer, I'll check it.

Comment: Posted as an answer. @Wen's solution is also sufficient.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply specify the row index of the header when you read the Excel file:

```
pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', header = 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can fix it when you read the excel

```
df=pd.read_excel(r'TT.xlsx',skiprows=1)
df
Out[367]: 
        Date           Name          Name_2   Abr   Number           
0 2010-12-01   Company Name        Somecity   Chi       36        NaN
1 2010-12-02   Company Name   Someothercity   Nyc      156        NaN
```